# Rspec: run clean up code before force quitting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm not using transactional tests. Instead, I'm manually reverting the database using DatabaseCleaner after each test:

```
after(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation }
```

However, if I force quit RSpec, the database doesn't get reverted. How can I run DatabaseCleaner before force quitting?

Comment: What kind of force quit are you using? CTRL+C? CTRL+\? If you kill it too aggressively (e.g. `kill -9` as an emergency stop) you're terminating it so hard it can't possibly clean up anything.

Comment: Ctrl + C twice. First time it tells me it's printing summary (but either freezes or takes too long), second time it actually quits

Comment: The second break forces it to abandon whatever it's doing and hard-terminate. This prevents it from running your clean-up process. You either need to figure out what's causing it to stall, or wrap it in a process that can clean up for you. If possible, move this `after` earlier in the chain so perhaps it can run before whatever slow thing that blocks it does.

Answer (score 0):

There's really not reliable way to clean up after a force-quite. But you can perform a clean up before starting:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
  end
end
```

If you're worried about the performance, you can do something like this:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation if File.exists?('tmp/spec_db_might_be_dirty')
    FileUtils.touch('tmp/spec_db_might_be_dirty')
  end

  config.after(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation 
    FileUtils.rm('tmp/spec_db_might_be_dirty')
  end
end
```

A special "marker" file will be created at the start of the suite, and will stay there if the force quit happens before DatabaseCleaner is done doing it's job.

If it's not force quit - it's will be removed in the `after` hook.